# A query on how to pass from convergence of subsequence to convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

In the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82205/derivatives-of-a-series-of-monotone-functions?rq=1), the accepted answer states that, for some subsequence $\{N_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, $F_{N_k}'\to f'(x)$ for almost-every $x\in[a,b]$, and then seems to assume that this implies that  $F_{N}'\to f'(x)$. Why does this holds? Is this due to the fact that for each subsequence $N_k$, we can take a further subsequence $N_{k_{l}}$ such that $F_{N_{k_l}}'\to f'(x)$?

Comment: It is because $F_n'$ is non-decreasing.